# Does anyone know about lower and upper limits for generation in cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am investigating [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) about generations of blobs in cloud storage and I can not find any information about available ranges for generations in the documentation.

I tried to create totally new blob and it has generation similar to 1672680951132943.

My questions is - does this range exist for generations in cloud storage?

Comment: Are you talking about versioning? If so, there is a fixed number of versions allowable and the oldest versions get overwritten as new versions arrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "the end of time". If you are familiar with Unix timestamp, you can see that is only the timestamp of the blob creation. You can have a quick check [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

[image]